# Sound coming out from speaker and headphone on an Acer Aspire One Model 722

Tags: 11.04, sound, headphones, speakers

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 on Acer Aspire One Model 722. The problem is that sound keep coming out from the internal speaker even after plugging the headphone in. Now, I am a beginner in the Ubuntu AND Linux world. I would appreciate every detailed help.

Running alsamixer I noticed that the Headphone Jack Sense doesn't exist at all. I'm wondering if there are interim steps that need to be taken.

Thank YOU!

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved following the fixes on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811178