# When I play music on my ubuntu 13.04 Dell XPS 13 FHD laptop the sound plays through the headphones and speakers at the same time

Tags: 13.04, laptop, hardware, headphones, speakers

I tried the settings mention in this topic:
[Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)

but with no luck.
The first thing i tried was to edit analog-output-headphones.conf but when i did that, i could no longer play from the laptop's speakers but only from headphones.
Then I tried the second suggestion of editing /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf which prevents the soundcard from loading first - in that case the sound keeps coming from both headphones and speakers.
any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/4727/sound-plays-on-headphones-and-speakers-at-the-same-time-with-lenovo-thinkpad?rq=1 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/78774/sound-from-headphones-and-speakers-in-ubuntu-11-10?rq=1 & also http://askubuntu.com/questions/101410/sound-coming-out-from-speaker-and-headphone-on-an-acer-aspire-one-model-722?rq=1 Take a look, you may find the answer in one of these

Comment: Unfortunately none of the above fixes worked for me, I've already checked them before posting my own question